# Pandas: Best way to calculate difference between multiple set paired rows

Tags: timestamp, pairing

I have a current data frame:

```
timestamp               Action          
2022-11-02 12:08:51     Started
2022-11-02 12:10:16     Completed
2022-11-02 12:23:40     Started
2022-11-02 12:25:01     Completed
2022-11-02 12:25:01     Started
2022-11-02 12:25:01     Completed
...                     ...
...                     ...
```

I have already converted the timestamp format so that it can perform subtraction. I hope to find the duration between every other row and the one before it (i.e. 1st row from 2nd row, 3rd from the 4th and so forth)

Lastly, I would like to sum up the differences and get the total time spent.

What would be the best to achieve this using python pandas?